# Can't set GWT compiler to output PRETTY code

Tags: gwt

When I set style property as in SuperDevMode tutorial I'm getting error "Unknown argument: -style". It looks like there is no "style" switch. How can I ask compiler to not obfuscate the output code?

```
Running GPE launcher for GWT-2.6.x version.
Unknown argument: -style
Google Web Toolkit 2.6.1
DevMode [-[no]startServer] [-port port-number | "auto"] [-whitelist whitelist-string] [-blacklist blacklist-string] [-logdir directory] [-logLevel level] [-gen dir] [-bindAddress host-name-or-address] [-codeServerPort port-number | "auto"] [-[no]superDevMode] [-server servletContainerLauncher[:args]] [-startupUrl url] [-war dir] [-deploy dir] [-extra dir] [-workDir dir] module[s]
```

I have tried GWT vesions 2.6.1 and 2.7.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Current version of GWT is 2.8, 2.7 was released in late 2014.

GWT 2.8 is the first version that supports the style flag for super dev mode.

See https://gwt.googlesource.com/gwt/+/be738ee668b427f5c484f3d008bc4ebd1230da6b for the diff that introduced this missing flag.